# link redirection using htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have these links in my website:

www.example.org/folder/files.php?file=folder/document.pdf

www.example.org/folder/files.php?force&file=2009.pdf

---

and I want redirect to :

www.example.org/files/folder/document.pdf

www.example.org/files/2009.pdf

I tried :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /files.php?file=$1 [R=301,L]  
</IfModule>
```

but doesn't work!
any help?

Comment: Please list what you have tried so far with your rewrite rules. This is a very common question and you can find many answers by searching here - only post a question if you've actually tried something first and are stuck.

Comment: I tried 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /files.php?file=$1 [R=301,L]  
</IfModule>

but doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /files.php?file=$1 [R=301,L]`

There are two issues with this rule ... first, what you are matching needs to appear first in the rule, then what you are rewriting appears second - you have that backwards.

Once you reverse that, though, you run into the second issue - you can't match query strings in a RewriteRule, you need to match them in a RewriteCond:

To match `www.example.org/folder/files.php?force&file=2009.pdf` and redirect it to `www.example.org/files/2009.pdf` you would do:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^force&file=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/files.php$ /files/%1 [R=301, L]
```

The `%1` matches what's in the parentheses in the RewriteCond.

Answer (score 0):

Search on google first. The first thing displayed on google for htaccess is htaccess redirect. I think
`Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html` (same line with a space) should work. Go to http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F . Php would also do the work. Just goolgle things before asking them.